# how to attach keydown keycode to a div box when open then unattach when closed in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to have multiple div dialogs that hold different image gallery and when one opens that specific div dialog box the left and right keys bind  and changes the images. the problem is that when you open one div and change the images to the next. another unopened the div box also changes.So how would i bind when open and close to specif div/dialog page

This the code that i have for the left and right
how to had if id/dialog click or open keycode active else not active

```
enter code here
 onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
     //left <- show Prev image
     changeImage(-1);

    }  

    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right -> show next image
            changeImage(+1);

     }



     if (e.keyCode == '37') {
     //left <- show Prev image
     changeImage2(-1);

    }  

    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right -> show next image

            changeImage2(+1);


     }



}
```

```js
// Get the modal
var modalBleach = document.getElementById('myModalMangaBleach');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btnBleach = document.getElementById("myBtnBleach");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spanBleach = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBleach")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btnBleach.onclick = function() {
    modalBleach.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
spanBleach.onclick = function() {
    modalBleach.style.display = "none";
 }

     
// Get the modal
var modalBleachVol1 = document.getElementById('myModalMangaBleachVol1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btnBleachVol1 = document.getElementById("myBtnBleachVol1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spanBleachVol1 = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBleachVol1")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btnBleachVol1.onclick = function() {
    modalBleachVol1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
spanBleachVol1.onclick = function() {
    modalBleachVol1.style.display = "none";
 }

// Get the modal
var modalBleachVol2 = document.getElementById('myModalMangaBleachVol2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btnBleachVol2 = document.getElementById("myBtnBleachVol2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spanBleachVol2 = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBleachVol2")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btnBleachVol2.onclick = function() {
    modalBleachVol2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
spanBleachVol2.onclick = function() {
    modalBleachVol2.style.display = "none";
 }


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
     window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modalBleach) {
        modalBleach.style.display = "none";
    }
 
 if (event.target == modalBleachVol1) {
        modalBleachVol1.style.display = "none";
    }
 
 if (event.target == modalBleachVol2) {
        modalBleachVol2.style.display = "none";
    }
 
}

     
     
     var bleachvol1 =[
        "https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/Volumes/Volume1/Bleach_01_01_01.jpg",
        "https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/Volumes/Volume1/Bleach_01_01_02.jpg",
  "https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/Volumes/Volume1/Bleach_01_01_03.jpg",
  
];




var imageNumber=0;
var imageLength = bleachvol1.length - 1;


 
 function changeImage(x){
     imageNumber +=x;

     //if youve reached end of array...sart all over to 0 
    if (imageNumber > imageLength){
    imageNumber = 0;
 }
 
 if (imageNumber < 0){
  imageNumber = imageLength;
 }
 

  document.getElementById('bleachImg1').src = bleachvol1[imageNumber];

  
  return false;
 
 }


 
 
  var bleachvol2 =[
 "https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/Volumes/Volume2/Bleach_02_01_00.jpg",
 "https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/Volumes/Volume2/Bleach_02_01_01.jpg",
 "https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/Volumes/Volume2/Bleach_02_01_02.jpg",
 "https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/Volumes/Volume2/Bleach_02_01_03.jpg",

 
];

var imageNumber2=0;
var imageLength2 = bleachvol2.length - 1;
 
  function changeImage2(x){
  imageNumber2 +=x;
     //if youve reached end of array...sart all over to 0 

  if (imageNumber2 > imageLength2){
    imageNumber2 = 0;
 }
 if (imageNumber2 < 0){
  imageNumber2 = imageLength2;
 
 }
 
    document.getElementById('bleachImg2').src = bleachvol2[imageNumber2];
  
  return false;
 
 }
     
     
     
     onkeydown = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
         //left <- show Prev image
   changeImage(-1);
  
        }  
  
  else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            // right -> show next image
    changeImage(+1);
   
         }
  
  
  
   if (e.keyCode == '37') {
         //left <- show Prev image
   changeImage2(-1);
  
        }  
  
  else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            // right -> show next image
   
    changeImage2(+1);

   
         }
  
  
     
    }
    
    
function scrollToTop(callback) {
    if ($('.modal-contentBleachChapter').scrollTop(0)) {
        $('.modal-contentBleachChapter').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, callback);
  $('.bleachImg').fadeOut(1);
  $('.bleachImg').fadeIn(1);
 
  
  
  
  
  
  
        return;false
  
 
    }

 
    callback();
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modalBleach {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */

.modal-contentBleach {
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 85%;
 max-height:90%;
    overflow-y:auto;
 overflow-x:hide;
 position:relative;
}

.modal-contentBleach li{
    
    margin-left:4px;
 margin-right:4px;
   width:210px;
   height:315px;
   background-color: #888888 ;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px black;
   display:inline-block;
  
}

.modal-contentBleach ul{
    padding:0px;
 white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y:hide;
 overflow-x:auto;
  
}
.modalBleachChapter {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 0px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-contentBleachChapter{
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 85%;
 max-height:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
 position:relative;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}


@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
   .modal-contentBleach li{
    width:180px;
    height:270px;
}

}

/* The Close Button */
.closeBleach, .closeBleachVol1,.closeBleachVol2  {
 color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
 display:inline-table;
 position:fixed;
 top:20px;
 left:40px;
 
}

.closeBleach:hover,
.closeBleach:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.closeBleachVol1:hover,
.closeBleachVol1 :focus
.closeBleachVol2:hover,
.closeBleachVol2 :focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.BleachCover{
background-image: url('https://www1.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/bleach_skull.png');
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;

width:100%;
height:100%;

display:block;
}

.BleachVol1{
background-image:url("https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/BleachVolCover/BleachVol1.jpg");
background-size:100% 100%;
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:100%;
border-radius:10px;
position:relative;
}

.BleachVol2{
background-image:url('https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/BleachVolCover/BleachVol2.jpg');
background-size:100% 100%;
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:100%;
width:100%;
border-radius:10px;
position:relative;

}


.gradBlue {
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
background: blue; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000014,#000027,#00003b,#00004e,#000062,#000076,#000089,#00009d,#0000b1,#0000c4,#0000d8,#0000eb, #0000ff,#1414ff,#2727ff,#3b3bff,#4e4eff,#6262ff,#7676ff,#8989ff,#9d9dff,#b1b1ff,#c4c4ff,#d8d8ff); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#000014,#000027,#00003b,#00004e,#000062,#000076,#000089,#00009d,#0000b1,#0000c4,#0000d8,#0000eb, #0000ff,#1414ff,#2727ff,#3b3bff,#4e4eff,#6262ff,#7676ff,#8989ff,#9d9dff,#b1b1ff,#c4c4ff,#d8d8ff); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#000014,#000027,#00003b,#00004e,#000062,#000076,#000089,#00009d,#0000b1,#0000c4,#0000d8,#0000eb, #0000ff,#1414ff,#2727ff,#3b3bff,#4e4eff,#6262ff,#7676ff,#8989ff,#9d9dff,#b1b1ff,#c4c4ff,#d8d8ff); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#000014,#000027,#00003b,#00004e,#000062,#000076,#000089,#00009d,#0000b1,#0000c4,#0000d8,#0000eb, #0000ff,#1414ff,#2727ff,#3b3bff,#4e4eff,#6262ff,#7676ff,#8989ff,#9d9dff,#b1b1ff,#c4c4ff,#d8d8ff); /* Standard syntax */
}
.gradBlue:hover{
background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d8d8ff,#c4c4ff,#b1b1ff,#9d9dff,#8989ff,#7676ff,#6262ff,#4e4eff,#3b3bff,#2727ff,#1414ff, #0000ff,#0000eb,#0000d8,#0000c4,#0000b1,#00009d,#000089,#000076,#000062,#00004e,#00003b,#000027,#000014); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#d8d8ff,#c4c4ff,#b1b1ff,#9d9dff,#8989ff,#7676ff,#6262ff,#4e4eff,#3b3bff,#2727ff,#1414ff, #0000ff,#0000eb,#0000d8,#0000c4,#0000b1,#00009d,#000089,#000076,#000062,#00004e,#00003b,#000027,#000014); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d8d8ff,#c4c4ff,#b1b1ff,#9d9dff,#8989ff,#7676ff,#6262ff,#4e4eff,#3b3bff,#2727ff,#1414ff, #0000ff,#0000eb,#0000d8,#0000c4,#0000b1,#00009d,#000089,#000076,#000062,#00004e,#00003b,#000027,#000014); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#d8d8ff,#c4c4ff,#b1b1ff,#9d9dff,#8989ff,#7676ff,#6262ff,#4e4eff,#3b3bff,#2727ff,#1414ff, #0000ff,#0000eb,#0000d8,#0000c4,#0000b1,#00009d,#000089,#000076,#000062,#00004e,#00003b,#000027,#000014); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<div class="MainPanel1"  style="width:90%;">
    <ul>
      <li>
   <div id="myBtnBleach" class="gradBlue">
   <div  class="BleachCover"></div>
   </div>
   </li>
   

    </ul>

</div>



<div id="myModalMangaBleach" class="modalBleach">

    <!-- Modal content--->
 <span class="closeBleach">&times;</span>
 <div class="modal-contentBleach">
    
 <center>
    <ul>
    <li  id="myBtnBleachVol1" class="BleachVol1"></li>
 
 <li  id="myBtnBleachVol2" class="BleachVol2"></li>


    </ul>
 
 </center>
 
  
</div>

</div>



<div id="myModalMangaBleachVol1" class="modalBleachChapter" >

    <!-- Modal content--->
 <span class="closeBleachVol1"><i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:36px"></i></span>
    <div class="modal-contentBleachChapter" id="modal-contentBleachChapter">
 <center>
  <div id="BleachVol2" onkeydown='' onclick='scrollToTop();' style="position:relative;border:green solid 2px;margin:auto;">
     <img

      onclick='changeImage(+1);return false;'
   class='bleachImg'
      id='bleachImg1' 
  
      src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/Volumes/Volume1/Bleach_01_01_01.jpg"
      />
 </div>
   <a href="#" style="position:fixed;display:block;bottom:0px;left:8%;border:2px lime solid;width:100px;background-color:green;"
     type='button'  value='prev' onclick='scrollToTop();changeImage(-1); return false;'><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" style="font-size:36px"></i></a>
  
  <a href="#" style="position:fixed;display:block;bottom:0px;right:10%;border:2px lime solid;width:100px;background-color:green;"
     type='button'  value='next' onclick='scrollToTop();changeImage(+1); return false;'
      
  ><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:36px"></i></a>
    
     </div>
  </center>
 
</div>

<div id="myModalMangaBleachVol2" class="modalBleachChapter">

    <!-- Modal content--->
 <span class="closeBleachVol2"><i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:36px"></i></span>
    <div class="modal-contentBleachChapter" id="modal-contentBleachChapter">
 <center>
  <div onclick='scrollToTop();' style="display:block;position:relative;border:green solid 2px;margin:auto;">
     <img
      
      onclick='changeImage2(+1);return false;'
   class='bleachImg'
      id='bleachImg2'
 
      src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/9/3/5/2/93529890/custom_themes/678622397973825322/files/Manga/Bleach/Volumes/Volume2/Bleach_02_01_00.jpg"
      />
 </div>
   <a href="#" style="position:fixed;display:block;bottom:0px;left:8%;border:2px lime solid;width:100px;background-color:green;"
     type='button'  value='prev' onclick='scrollToTop();changeImage2(-1); return false;'><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" style="font-size:36px"></i></a>
  
  <a href="#" style="position:fixed;display:block;bottom:0px;right:10%;border:2px lime solid;width:100px;background-color:green;"
     type='button'  value='next' onclick='scrollToTop();changeImage2(+1); return false;'
      
  ><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:36px"></i></a>
    
     </div>
  </center>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an onclick event handler for all elements of the class of your clickable divs. In the onclick handler, define the keydown handlers for this exact div.

Now, when you click the "X" (or however you can close the gallery), set an onclick event handler for that to remove the keydown event handlers for the current opened div and then close the div.

Comment: <span class="closeBleachVol2"><i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:36px"></i></span>

Comment: and this are the two div <li  id="myBtnBleachVol1" class="BleachVol1"></li>
 
 <li  id="myBtnBleachVol2" class="BleachVol2"></li> so i think you mean for onclick like this <li  id="myBtnBleachVol1" class="BleachVol1" onclick="event Handler or function()"></li>
 
 <li  id="myBtnBleachVol2" class="BleachVol2" onclick="event Handler or function()"></li>

Comment: also im a slow learner but until u answer i'll research handler events and examples